# Troubleshooting AJAX form submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm scratching my head with this one at the moment - if any of you could help that'd be amazing. I have a site which uses AJAX to submit a contact form after a simple validation. All goes well, and the site acts as if the email has sent, but I'm not receiving any emails (yep I've triple checked, it's the right email address).

Here's what I'm working with:

**HTML / PHP**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/contact.js"></script>

...

<section id="contact">

<span class="contact_results"></span>

<div class="form">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="contactname" required value="<? echo $user_name ?>" placeholder="Your Name:" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required value="<? echo $email ?>" placeholder="Your E-Mail Address:" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="phone" name="phone" id="phone" value="<? echo $phone ?>" placeholder="Your Telephone Number:" autocomplete="off">
    <textarea name="message" id="message" required placeholder="Your Message:"><? echo $message ?></textarea>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" id="contactbutton">Submit Form</button>
</div>

</section>
```

**Contact.js**

```
$(function() {

    $("#contact button").click(function() {

        var proceed = true;
        //simple validation at client's end
        //loop through each field and we simply change border color to red for invalid fields       
        $("#contact input[required=true], #contact textarea[required=true]").each(function(){
            $(this).css('border-color','#EEE'); 
            if(!$.trim($(this).val())){ //if this field is empty 
                $(this).css('border-color','#FC0'); //change border color to red   
                proceed = false; //set do not proceed flag
            }
            //check invalid email
            var email_reg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/; 
            if($(this).attr("type")=="email" && !email_reg.test($.trim($(this).val()))){
                $(this).css('border-color','#FC0'); //change border color to red   
                proceed = false; //set do not proceed flag              
            }   
        });

        if(proceed) //everything looks good! proceed...
        {

            //get input field values data to be sent to server
            post_data = {
                'user_name'     : $('input[name=name]').val(), 
                'user_email'    : $('input[name=email]').val(), 
                'user_phone'    : $('input[name=phone]').val(),  
                'msg'           : $('textarea[name=message]').val()
            };

            //Ajax post data to server
            $.post('contact_sendform.php', post_data, function(response){  
                if(response.type == 'error'){ //load json data from server and output message     
                    output = '<span class="error">'+response.text+'</span>';
                }else{
                    output = '<span class="success">'+response.text+'</span>';
                    //reset values in all input fields
                    $("#contact  input[required=true], #contact textarea[required=true]").val(''); 
                    $(".form").fadeOut(400); //hide form after success
                }
                $("#contact .contact_results").hide().html(output).slideDown(400);
            }, 'json');
        }
    });

    //reset previously set border colors and hide all message on .keyup()
    $("#contact  input[required=true], #contact textarea[required=true]").keyup(function() { 
        $(this).css('border-color',''); 
        $("#result").slideUp();
    });
});
```

**contact_sendform.php**

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
$to_email       = "xxxxxxxx@hotmail.com";

//check if its an ajax request, exit if not
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {

    $output = json_encode(array(            //create JSON data
        'type'=>'error', 
        'text' => 'Sorry Request must be Ajax POST'
    ));
    die($output); //exit script outputting json data
} 

//Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
$user_name      = filter_var($_POST["user_name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$user_email     = filter_var($_POST["user_email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$user_phone     = filter_var($_POST["user_phone"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$message        = filter_var($_POST["msg"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

//additional php validation
if(strlen($user_name)<3){ // If length is less than 4 it will output JSON error.
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Name is too short or empty!'));
    die($output);
}
if(!filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ //email validation
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Please enter a valid email!'));
    die($output);
}
if(strlen($message)<3){ //check emtpy message
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Too short message! Please enter something.'));
    die($output);
}

//email body
$message_body = $message."\r\n\r\n-".$user_name."\r\nEmail : ".$user_email."\r\nPhone Number : ". $user_phone ;

// Set Subject
$subject = "Ian! You've got a new message from ".$user_name;

//proceed with PHP email.
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$headers .= 'From: '.$user_email."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$user_email."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$send_mail = mail($to_email, $subject, $message_body, $headers);

if(!$send_mail)
{
    //If mail couldn't be sent output error. Check your PHP email configuration (if it ever happens)
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'));
    die($output);
}else{
    $userArray = explode(' ', trim($user_name));
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Thanks for getting in touch, '.$userArray[0] .'!'));
    die($output);
}
}
?>
```

As I said - when the form is submitted with the correct data, it displays the confirmation message which only fires when $sendMail works - so I'm at a loss as to what's going wrong. Any insight or help would be majorly appreciated - thanks! :)

Comment: Is this site live? or on your local machine? maybe it is a server problem.

Comment: It's live buddy, also 99% sure it's not a server problem

Comment: have you tried the code without the ajax?

Comment: How'd you mean Madalin? It's all going through with no errors, just doesn't appear to actually be sending the e-mail (but it thinks it did send it) :)

Comment: Have you checked your server's error logs?

Comment: So many things can go wrong when sending an email. I suggest you take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php especially the comment section. Make sure your SMTP configuration is valid. Then you might want to check your spam folder, as your email provider might be marking the emails as spam.

Comment: Thanks guys. I think it may have just been the server actually (apologies emcee22!) - I haven't changed anything and it's working now! Thanks for the help guys